# Can not connect to Infura Mainnet

Tags: web3.py, infura

I am looking at the infura documentation and no matter what method I am trying to authenticate my project id I am getting errors such as the one displayed below or 404 errors. Has anyone had the same issue and found a solution? I am trying to connect to the eth mainnet.

```
(venv) C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\UniswapQuery>curl --user :https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[my project id]
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
```

This is the python code that refers to the infura network:

```
infura_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[my project id]'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use the built-in Infura mainnet object:

At the command line:

```
$ export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=<project id>
$ export WEB3_INFURA_API_SECRET=<secret>
```

Then in Python:

```
>>> from web3.auto.infura.mainnet import w3
>>> w3.isConnected()
True
>>> w3.eth.block_number
12642083
```

Comment: Unfortunately the command line code gives me errors and the 'from web3.auto.infura.mainnet import w3' is saying that it isnt recognized

Comment: You have likely wrong Web3.py version

Comment: @Reece What is the exact error you are getting when you try that import?